# CSS keep height when image when floating

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a photo that has the `float: left` attribute and text is right next to it, like this:

```
<div id='1'>
 <img src='img.jpg' width='50%' style='float:left;' />
  This is text next to it<br/><br/>More text
</div>
```

I don't know the dimensions of the image, or the height of the text, but the text is often shorter than the image, causing the div to be shorter than the image (which looks really bad). Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Try using style `overflow:auto` in the `div`; or wrap the texts into another div containing style `clear:both`

Comment: See http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to your first `div`.

Addicionally `ids` and `classes` in `CSS` can not start from numbers.

Comment: Thankyou, i knew the answer would be that simple

Answer (score 0):

I think the optimal solution is to add new div at the end and clear everything with it. like this:

CSS in first case:

```
#1:after{
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block; 
}
```

Second case:
HTML:

```
<div id='1'>
 <img src='img.jpg' width='50%' style='float:left;'>
  This is text next to it<br><br>More text
  <div class="cl"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cl {
clear: both;
}
```

or if you want to run in the oldest versions of IE you can add:

```
.cl { 
font-size: 0; 
line-height: 0; 
text-indent: -4000px; 
clear: both;
}
```